# How to restore checkpoint in Tensorflow 2.0.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I was building a self-defined encoder-decoder tf.keras.Model and saved my checkpoint. After closing my Jupyter notebook and open it again trying to restore my encoder-decoder parameters, I surprisingly found that it is not working. I am not sure it's that I understand the usage wrong or something was wrong with my steps of doing it. Here is my code.

```
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer,
                                 encoder=encoder,
                                 decoder=decoder)

tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)

EPOCHS = 10
TOLERANCE = 0.08

start = time.time()
for epoch in range(1, EPOCHS+1):
    epoch_start = time.time()

    # train the encoder-decoder model
    batch = 0
    total_loss = 0
    total_accuracy = 0
    for inp, targ in dataset.take(STEP_PER_EPOCH):
        batch += 1

        batch_loss, batch_accuracy = train_step(inp, targ, phoneme_tokenizer)
        total_loss += batch_loss
        total_accuracy += batch_accuracy

        print("Epoch: {}/{}  Batch: {}  Loss: {:.4f}  Accuracy: {:.4f}  Time: {:.0f}s".
              format(epoch, EPOCHS, batch, batch_loss.numpy(), batch_accuracy.numpy(), time.time()-epoch_start), 
              end="\r")

        if batch % 1000 == 0:
            print()
    print()
    # saving (checkpoint) the model when total loss is less than 0.9
    checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix)

    # validation process
    total_val_loss = 0
    total_val_acc = 0
    for val_inp, val_targ in dataset_val.take(VAL_WAV_SIZE):
        val_loss, val_acc = validate_step(val_inp, val_targ, phoneme_tokenizer)
        total_val_loss += val_loss
        total_val_acc += val_acc

    # print out the epoch results
    mean_total_acc = total_accuracy / STEP_PER_EPOCH
    mean_total_loss = total_loss / STEP_PER_EPOCH

    mean_val_acc = total_val_acc / VAL_WAV_SIZE
    mean_val_loss = total_val_loss / VAL_WAV_SIZE

    print("\n================================")
    print("Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch, EPOCHS))
    print('Accuracy: {:.4f}  Loss: {:.4f}  val_acc: {:.4f}  val_loss: {:.4f}'.format(
        mean_total_acc, 
        mean_total_loss, 
        mean_val_acc,
        mean_val_loss))
    print('Time taken for epoch {}: {:.2f} min'.format(epoch, (time.time() - epoch_start)/60))
    print('Total Time taken: {:.2f} min'.format((time.time() - start)/60))
    print("================================\n")

    if mean_total_loss < TOLERANCE and mean_val_acc > 0.5:
        break
```

After running the code above, it showed **no errors and I got my checkpoints files in my directory**. I closed my Jupyter notebook and built all the objects(which are my encoder and decoder) without training and typed

```
checkpoint.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
```

hoped that the parameters would come back and I can start my prediction but I just got pretty poor outcome anyway, which was against the outcome predicted after training right away. Should I add some more lines for restoring all the parameters or something else?

Below are more details about my encoder decoder structure, and my input shape is (batch size, 99, 13)

```
class ResnetIdentityBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
        super(ResnetIdentityBlock, self).__init__()
        self.filters1, self.filters2, self.filters3 = filters

        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(self.filters1, 1, padding='valid')
        self.bn1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(self.filters2, kernel_size, padding='same')
        self.bn2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(self.filters3, 1, padding='valid')
        self.bn3 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x = self.conv1(input_tensor)
        x = self.bn1(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)

        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x, training=training)

        x += input_tensor
        return tf.nn.relu(x)

class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    '''
    Encoder for MFCC transformed wave data
    '''
    def __init__(self, 
                 lstm_units, 
                 batch_sz, 
                 dropout_rate, 
                 units,
                 squeeze_time):
        '''
        Args:
            lstm_units: LSTM units number
            batch_sz: batch size            
            dropout_rate: layer dropout ratio
            rnn_initial_weight: type of weight initialization
        '''
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.lstm_units = lstm_units    
        self.squeeze_time = squeeze_time

        # conv1d
        self.feat_extract = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=units, activation="relu")
        self.feat_dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)

        # ResNet
        self.resnet1 = ResnetIdentityBlock(kernel_size=11, filters=[units, units, units])

        units *= squeeze_time
        self.resnet2 = ResnetIdentityBlock(kernel_size=7, filters=[units, units, units])

        units *= squeeze_time
        self.resnet3 = ResnetIdentityBlock(kernel_size=3, filters=[units, units, units])

        # Encoder lstm
        self.enc_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=lstm_units, 
                                             return_sequences=True, 
                                             return_state=True, 
                                             kernel_initializer="lecun_normal",
                                             activation='tanh', 
                                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', 
                                             recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', 
                                             dropout=dropout_rate)

    def call(self, inputs):
        '''
        call pyramidal LSTM neural network encoder

        Args:
            inputs: wave input
        '''
        x = self.feat_extract(inputs)
        x = self.feat_dropout(x)

        # ResNet
        x = self.resnet1(x)
        x = self.reshape_pyramidal(x)

        x = self.resnet2(x)
        x = self.reshape_pyramidal(x)

        x = self.resnet3(x)

        # encoder output layer
        fw_outputs, fw_state_h, fw_state_c = self.enc_lstm(x)

        return fw_outputs, fw_state_h, fw_state_c

    def reshape_pyramidal(self, outputs):
        '''
        After concatenating forward and backward outputs
        return the reshaped output

        Args:
            outputs: outputs from LSTM
            squeeze_time: time step one would like to squeeze in pyramidal LSTM
        '''
        batch_size, time_steps, num_units = outputs.shape

        return tf.reshape(outputs, (batch_size, -1, num_units * self.squeeze_time))    

class LuongAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(LuongAttention, self).__init__()
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation="relu")
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation="relu")
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="relu")

    def call(self, query, values):
        # query hidden state shape == (batch_size, hidden size)
        # query_with_time_axis shape == (batch_size, 1, hidden size)
        # values shape == (batch_size, max_len, hidden size)
        # we are doing this to broadcast addition along the time axis to calculate the score
        query_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(query, 1)

        # score shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
        # we get 1 at the last axis because we are applying score to self.V
        # the shape of the tensor before applying self.V is (batch_size, max_length, units)
        score = self.V(tf.nn.tanh(
            self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))

        # attention_weights shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

        # context_vector shape after sum == (batch_size, hidden_size)
        context_vector = attention_weights * values
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

        return context_vector, attention_weights

class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    '''
    Decoder for output phonemes
    '''
    def __init__(self, 
                 target_sz, 
                 embedding_dim, 
                 lstm_units, 
                 batch_sz, 
                 dropout_rate):
        '''
        Args:
            target_sz: target size, total phoneme size in this case
            embedding_dim: embedding dimension
            lstm_units: LSTM units number
            batch_sz: batch size
            dropout_rate: dropout ratio
            rnn_initial_weight: type of weight initialization
        '''
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.batch_sz = batch_sz
        self.target_sz = target_sz
        self.lstm_units = lstm_units
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(target_sz, embedding_dim)

        # attention model
        self.attention = LuongAttention(lstm_units)

        # decoder rnn            
        self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=lstm_units, 
                                          return_sequences=True, 
                                          return_state=True, 
                                          kernel_initializer="lecun_normal",
                                          activation='tanh',
                                          recurrent_activation='sigmoid', 
                                          recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', 
                                          dropout=dropout_rate)

        # Fully-connected
        self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")
        self.fc1_dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)

        self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_sz, activation="softmax")

        # build layer info dictionary
        self.layer_info = dict()


    def call(self, inputs, enc_hidden_h, enc_hidden_c, enc_output):
        '''
        call LSTM decoder

        Args:
            inputs: target output, following phoneme for wave data input in this case
            enc_hidden_h: encoder hidden state h
            enc_hidden_c: encoder hidden state c
            enc_output: encoder outputs
        '''
        # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
        x = self.embedding(inputs)

        # enc_output shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
        context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(enc_hidden_h, enc_output)

        # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
        x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)

        # passing the concatenated vector to the 2-layer LSTM (Decoder)
        x, state_h, state_c = self.lstm1(x)

        # dense layer before final predict output dense layer
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[-1]))
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc1_dropout(x)

        # output shape == (batch_size, phoneme size)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return x, (state_h, state_c), attention_weights
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, please share the complete code to reproduce your issue, so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness @TensorflowWarriors, I have edit my question to add more details of my model.